# Force redirect for certain files (based on referer) and trigger a 404 page otherwise

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We distribute different versions of a software product through a single download link. The delivery is based on the `referer` in conjunction with a default value, which works fine. In addition the user should be redirected to a `404`-page, in case the wrong filename was used.

At the moment the `.htaccess`-file looks like this:

```
# stop directory listing
Options -Indexes

# turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine On

# force 404 if file name is missing or wrong
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(download_mac\.zip|download_pc\.zip)$
RewriteRule (.*) 404/index.html [L]

# an example based on the referer
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([^.]+\.)*domain-a\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([^.]+\.)*domain-b\.com
RewriteRule ^(download_mac\.zip|download_pc\.zip)$ domain_ab/$1 [L]

# last rule if no referer matches
RewriteRule ^(download_mac\.zip|download_pc\.zip)$ default/$1 [L]
```

So I have one issue and one additional question with this file:

1. The first rule, to force 404, is very greedy and gets the error page *every* time, no matter what URL is called. I also tried single statements like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^download_mac\.zip$` without any effect. How can I fix this?
2. How can I get rid of the filenames in any other rule? I tried things like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ default/$1 [L]` but it gives me a hard time and an `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: REQUEST_URI always begins with a `/`, but your RewriteCond expects it to start with `download_…` which it never does. Include the leading slash for that RewriteCond not to match everything.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for pointing that out. In other `.htaccess`-files I used it the way you said with a leading slash - somehow it was gone missing this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid repeating your filenames by using an Env variable like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(download_mac\.zip|download_pc\.zip)$ - [E=ALLOWED:$1,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:ALLOWED} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /404/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:ALLOWED} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([^.]+\.)*domain-a\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([^.]+\.)*domain-b\.com
RewriteRule ^ /domain_ab/%{ENV:ALLOWED} [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:ALLOWED} !^$
RewriteRule ^ /default/%{ENV:ALLOWED} [L]
```

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. This works perfectly. I never used any env variables in a `.htaccess` before but now I have an idea how to use them. Thanks for that too.

Answer (score 1):

You can just move the rewrite rule to the end. The other rules handle the valid cases and if none of them matches the last rule applies

```
# an example based on the referer
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://([^.]+\.)*domain-[ab]\.com
RewriteRule ^download_(mac|pc)\.zip$ domain_ab/$0 [L]

# last rule if no referer matches
RewriteRule ^download_(mac|pc)\.zip$ default/$0 [L]

# force 404 if file name is missing or wrong
RewriteRule ^ 404/index.html [L]
```

Comment: +1 I tried that before and it didn't work. As your code is fine, I guess I was missing something on my hand. Thanks for your help too.